# Cannot set permissions on Twitter to create a bot

Tags: php, twitter, bots

I'm using the BirdElephant PHP library to create a Twitter bot.

Authentication works but I can't change the permissions to **Read and write** instead of **Read only**.

I don't see where in the *Developer Twitter UI* I can make this change.

Other sources mention selecting OAuth 1.0 but I don't have this possibility because I don't see this toggle.

Please look at the screenshots.

Thanks for your help.

[Twitter UI 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onwRk.png)

[Twitter UI 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aguun.png)

Comment: Not really because as previously mentioned I don't have the toggle which enables me to enable OAuth 1.0A (see screenshot).

Comment: You will need to use OAuth 2.0 with PKCE for user authentication in this case. There is information in the BirdElephant website about this (note that it says you should prefer OAuth 2.0)